# In Cloudfront custom error responses, is there a way to force a redirect that updates the browser navigation bar?

Tags: redirect, amazon-cloudfront

I want to redirect all 403 errors to `/index.html`. If I add a custom error response in Cloudfront, it will serve up `index.html` if I go to `mywebsite/bad_page`, but keep `mywebsite/bad_page` in the browser navigation bar. I want it to completely redirect to `mywebsite`, removing the bad URL from the browser navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Error tab of CloudFront setting follow steps :

1. Select Error code like `403`
2. Give path `/index.html`
3. Set response code as `200`

See below :

[image: Image1]
[image: Image2]

If you want redirect `bad_pages` to `/index.html` then create S3 routing rules inside Properties ->  Static web hosting -> Redirection Rule

```
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <KeyPrefixEquals>bad_pages</KeyPrefixEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <ReplaceKeyWith>index.html</ReplaceKeyWith>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

Comment: That is how I currently have it set up, but as mentioned the navigation bar does not get updated when I go to the unrecognized path.

Comment: you want to show `bad_page` ? or want to route to different page ?

Comment: I want to route them to index.html, and remove the `bad_page` path from the browser navigation bar

Comment: If I do that, it goes to the bucket webpage instead of the one behind my domain in cloudfront.